# Curl tutorials & resources

Tags: php, curl

Could anyone share good resources/tutorials about php curl?

Answer (score 2):

Again, no offense, but google is your friend.

[PHP Curl Functions](https://www.php.net/curl) and a [LibCurl Tutorial by Zend](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1081)

Answer (score 1):

While I normally don't answer questions with "google it", in this case, the results for "php curl tutorial" on Google are actually pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

you can read this book **Michael Schrenk-Webbots, Spiders, and Screen Scrapers_ A Guide to Developing Internet Agents with PHP_CURL-No Starch Press (2012)** view the review  [http://www.amazon.com/Webbots-Spiders-Screen-Scrapers-Developing/dp/1593273975/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1392107672&sr=8-1&keywords=curl+php](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593273975)